# python multiple of 3 range function for loop with condition

Tags: python

Simple for loop with a condition: It should print "YES" at every multiple of 3. For every number that IS NOT a multiple of 3, it should just print the number normally. Very straightforward; all I get is a printing "YES".

```
for x in range(0, 100, 3):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print "YES"
    else:
        print x
```

ANSWER:

```
for x in range(0, 100):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print "THREE"
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        print "FIVE"
    elif (x % 3) and (x % 5):
        print "BOTH"
```

Comment: Your`range()` is only going over every 3rd element that is `0,3,6,9,12,... etc` m that is why you are getting only `Yes` , if you want to go over all the elements, use `range0,100)` without the step argument. (The third argument to `range()` is the step.

Comment: `range(0, 100, 3)` what do you expect study range function to understand it

Comment: I get it.. but snap. I think I will re-look this.

Comment: What is your question? What result are you looking for? And in what way does it differ from the result you're observing?

Comment: I edited the answer. I was trying to have different multiples print different strings. Python practice.

Answer (score 1):

range:

> > range(start, stop[, step])
> >
> > This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised).

your code should be like this:

```
for x in range(0, 100):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        print "YES"
    else:
        print x
```

examples:

```
>>> range(0,10)    // without step
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(0,10,3)  // with step
               ^
               step
[0, 3, 6, 9]
```

this is what you need:

```
>>> def myTest():
...     for x in range(100):
...         if x%3==0 and x%5==0:
...             print "Both"
...         elif x%3==0:
...             print "Three"
...         elif x%5==0:
...             print "Five"
...
```